# Camel ZipFileDataFormat splitting doesn't set the headers when streaming

Tags: apache-camel, splitter, camel-zipfile

I have a simple route which polls zip files from FTP server. The zip file consists of one file that needs processing and zero or more attachments.
I am trying to use ZipFileDataFormat for splitting and I'm able to split and route the items as desired i.e. send the processing file to the processor and other files to the aggregator endpoint.

The route looks like below:

```
from(sftp://username@server/folder/path?password=password&delay=600000)
.unmarshal(getZipFileDataFormat()).split(body(Iterator.class)).streaming()
.log("CamelSplitComplete :: ${header.CamelSplitComplete}")
.log("Split Size :: ${header.CamelSplitSize}")
 .choice()
   .when(header(MyConstants.CAMEL_FILE_NAME_HEADER).contains(".json"))
     .to(JSON_ENDPOINT).endChoice()
   .otherwise()
     .to(AGGREGATOR_ENDPOINT)
 .endChoice()
.end();
```

> getZipFileDataFormat

```
private ZipFileDataFormat getZipFileDataFormat() {
        ZipFileDataFormat zipFile = new ZipFileDataFormat();
        zipFile.setUsingIterator(true);
        return zipFile;
    }
```

> The splitting works fine. However, I can see in the logs that the two headers **CamelSplitComplete** and **CamelSplitSize** are not set correctly. Where CamelSplitComplete is always false, CamelSplitSize is not having any value.

Because of this, I am not able to aggregate based on the size. I am using **eagerCheckCompletion()** for getting the input exchange in the aggregator route. My aggregator route looks like below.

```
from(AGGREGATOR_ENDPOINT).aggregate(new ZipAggregationStrategy()).constant(true)
.eagerCheckCompletion().completionSize(header("CamelSplitSize"))to("file:///tmp/").end();
```

I read [Apache Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) that these headers are always set. Am I missing anything here? Any pointer in the right direction would be very helpful.

Comment: There is no `CamelSplitSize` when you use streaming mode on the splitter as documented. The completed should however be there.

Comment: Thanks @ClausIbsen! Is there a way to determine the number of files in the zip then? Can we use CamelSplitIndex - 1 to determine the number of files?

Comment: @ClausIbsen, it also says in the documentation that **From Camel 2.9 onwards this header is also set in stream based splitting, but only on the completed Exchange.** I am using 2.12.5

Comment: Try with newer version as 2.12.x is very very old

Comment: I manually set headers for correlation and completion size. Now, I'm getting right values in the aggregator route. However, no zip file is getting generated now. The exchange is processed without any error. The aggregator route now looks like this. `from(AGGREGATOR_ENDPOINT).log("Aggregated File Count :: ${header.totalFileCount}").log("Incoming File Name :: ${header.incomingFileName}").aggregate(header("incomingFileName"), new ZipAggregationStrategy()).completionSize(header("totalFileCount")).to("file:///tmp/").end();` Any pointers on why no zip file is getting generated?

Comment: @ClausIbsen - I am working with Websphere 7 and the greatest version of camel I can use is 2.13. Do you have any pointers on the aggregator route above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the whole route to work. I had to add a sort of pre-processor which would set some essential headers (Outgoing file name and file count of the zip) I'd require for aggregation.

```
from(sftp://username@server/folder/path?password=password&delay=600000).to("file:///tmp/")
.beanRef("headerProcessor").unmarshal(getZipFileDataFormat())
.split(body(Iterator.class)).streaming()    
 .choice()
   .when(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME).contains(".json"))
     .to(JSON_ENDPOINT).endChoice()
   .otherwise()
    .to(AGGREGATOR_ENDPOINT)
 .endChoice()
.end();
```

After that, the zip aggregation strategy worked as expected. Putting here the aggregation route just for completion of answer.

```
from(AGGREGATOR_ENDPOINT)
  .aggregate(header(MyConstants.HEADER_OUTGOING_FILE_NAME), new ZipAggregationStrategy())
  .eagerCheckCompletion().completionSize(header(MyConstants.HEADER_TOTAL_FILE_COUNT))
  .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${header.outgoingFileName}"))
 .to("file:///tmp/").end();
```

Comment: Kabira, I am trying to achieve something very similar. However, each file in the generated output zip has the exchanges ids, not the file names. I am using XML DSL, so to set file names I use <setHeader headerName="Exchange.FILE_NAME"><simple>${header.CamelFileName}</simple></setHeader>. This is done before calling the aggregator, editing the header.CamelFileName so output zip is named with the value of that header. However, inner files are named with their exchange id. Any idea?